# Android drawing path on mapview using map overlay and GeoPoints

Tags: android-layout, overlay, android-mapview

I am trying to draw a path between  a number of geepoints on a  map,whilst  i iterate through an arraylist of geopoints.  from this i am receiving a index out of bounds error, i have tired to debug it but haven't gotten any where. So could someone please point me in the right direction and thank you.

```
//making the array and inserting the geopoints
List <GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint> ();
    for (Iterator<Placemark> iter=places.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
        Placemark point = (Placemark)iter.next();

       points.add(new GeoPoint(p.getLatitude(),p.getLongitude()));


    }
//the loop which gives out a null exception
for (int j=0; j <points.size(); j++){
MyOverlay poin = new MyOverlay(points.get(j-1),points.get(j)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the loop like this,

```
for (int j=0; j <points.size()-1; j++){
MyOverlay poin = new MyOverlay(points.get(j),points.get(j+1)); }
```

if still didn't work, try this in the for loop,

```
j<points.size()-2
```

Comment: for (int j=1; j <points.size(); j++){
MyOverlay poin = new MyOverlay(points.get(j-1),points.get(j)); }